what happens to singular values with one-rank update?
I have a square matrix $A$ and two vectors $a$ and $b$ such that $\sum a_i = 1$ and $b_j = 1$ for all $j$.
I would like to know if there is some way of expressing the relationship between the singular values of $A$ and the singular values of $A + ab^{\top}$ (meaning, a relationship between $A$ and $A$ added with the outer product of $a$ and $b$).
Section 3.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08369.pdf looks promising, but not all the way through.

Do you just want an update to the singular values, or do you need the updated right and left singular vectors as well?  How accurate does this need to be?

I am not looking for a numerical recipe, I just want to know how the singular values change relative to the original one. It seems like the paper above gives quite a good solution, I think, but I didn't manage to extract the details.

There are numerical methods for updating the singular values and vectors, but I’m not aware of (and doubt it exists) a formula for the updated singular values.
